# Visualizing Geological heatmap: why plot is not showing?

Tags: python, plotly, geospatial

Here is a sample of a dataset i got, where 'lat', and 'lon' stand for 'latitude' and 'longitude', respectively:

| 'lat' | 'lon' |
| --- | --- |
| 25.09740093 | 55.1368825 |
| 25.11258035 | 55.2587537 |
| 25.0777321 | 55.13890908 |
| 25.1337145 | 55.192437 |
| 25.193982 | 55.2769135 |
| 25.0372255 | 55.216955 |
| 25.068809 | 55.326105 |

I tried to visualize it on map with plotly as such:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(go.Densitymapbox(lat=df['lat'], lon=df['lon']))
fig.show()
```

And got this output:
[image]

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Z-value for heatmap is required as well as latitude and longitude. A [reference](https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-density-heatmaps/#stamen-terrain-base-map-no-token-needed-density-mapbox-with-plotlygraphobjects) can be found here for your reference.
I specified the z-value directly in the graph code, but originally, there should be a column of z-values in the data frame, so in that case, specify the column name.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

fig = go.Figure(go.Densitymapbox(lat=df.lat,
                                 lon=df.lon,
                                 z=np.random.randint(10,100,7),
                                 radius=10))

fig.update_layout(
    mapbox_style="stamen-terrain",
    mapbox_center_lon=55.20,
    mapbox_center_lat=25.11,
    mapbox_zoom=9
)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

[image]